# how to update table with join?

Tags: plsql, merge, sql-update

In oracle db i have a table which include 2 varchar columns - new_val, old_val.
I need to update multiple tables which has several columns which include in their values the old_val from the 1st table mension above, and replace them with "new_val" from that table.

tried to perform the following but got an error:

```
UPDATE (SELECT a.account_id, b.new_val, b.old_val FROM
any_table a JOIN val_table b ON a.account_id  like    
'%'||b.old_val||'%') SET account_id= 
replace(account_id,old_val ,new_val);
```

Error: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table

I understand the error but can't find the proper solution.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
   UPDATE ANY_TABLE a
   SET account_id= (
       SELECT replace(a.account_id,b.old_val ,b.new_val)
       FROM VAL_TABLE b
       WHERE a.account_id like '%'||b.old_val||'%'
   )
   WHERE EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM VAL_TABLE b
      WHERE a.account_id like '%'||b.old_val||'%'
   );
```